# can i restore the previous value of a cell of a row in SQL server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have made a wrong entry in a cell and committed it. Later i found that that entry was actually suppose to be done to the below row cell, but i dont remember the previous value and want to know that can i still find it anywhere to make the correction.

Answer (score 1):

The backup is the best way to approach this, if the database is in properly full logged mode and the transaction is still in the transaction log, it can be pulled out and decoded manually, although the effort to do this is non-trivial.

I've written an example of doing this for an update. http://sqlfascination.com/2010/02/03/how-do-you-decode-a-simple-entry-in-the-transaction-log-part-1/

This really though is not a mechanism you should ever rely on to recover data, suitable backups / transactions or even paper backups would be better.

Comment: Nice post! You actually went through the quagmire (as you so rightly put it) +1 just for that! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Only real way that  i can think of would be by restoring a backup and using the value of that row from the backup.

Note: Retaining the references to  [transaction log restore method](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/log-files/can-the-transaction-log-tell-us-what-happened-.aspx) using [SQL log rescue](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Log_Rescue/) in case someone with SQL 2000 ever runs into a similar issue

Comment: First of all thanks for your kind answer and attention. Yes, i went through the article its informative but cant help me out of this.

Comment: Agree. In your case, atleast as far as i know, backups are your only real option.

Comment: but what if in case of mysql? Is the situation same?

Comment: Sorry. I am not much help when it comes to mysql. If you are keen to know about mysql, i suggest you re-tag your question as mysql so that it will attract the attention of some of the more knowledgeable mysql folks. They should be able to authoritatively tell you either way.

Answer (score 0):

I can add to all these goood answers that also SQL Litespeed tool has a very nice feature called Log Reader which can help you restore past values from Log backups (done with Litespeed) and even Online Transaction log (not backed up). I think a trial version of [Litespeed](http://www.quest.com/litespeed-for-sql-server/) will let you look into your online transaction log file - of course if your database is in Full recovery mode. Worth to try.